# Dropdown with Auto-complete Property

Tags: asp.net, cascadingdropdown

i have added a drop-down in my project now i want to add auto-complete property in this Drop down.
How to add autocomplete property in this dropdown please help..

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend using jquery UI for this one.

Take a look [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).